# bootstrap no-script fall-back for drop-down button

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to have an alternative to the bootstrap drop-down button in case a user does not have javascript enabled. Without javascript there is no drop-down and therefore the information is unavailable.
I would like to turn the button into a clickable link in case of deactivated javascript.
This is the [page](http://scip.zib.de), I am referring to the "Documentation" in the header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had the same problem and came up with this CSS to enable the Menus with NoScript active:

```
.dropdown-toggle:focus + .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

I think you need to remove the other `<noscript>` hack for it to work.

I only tested this in Firefox 29 yet...

Answer (score 1):

Just put a noscript tag with the links beneath it.

```
<noscript> 
  <ul> 
    <li><a href="script.html">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="object.html">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="select.html">Link 1</a></li>
  </ul> 
</noscript>
```

This will just be shown if javascript is dactivated.

Comment: It's even easier (at least if we can live with some less functionality): just add the link as href in the <li class="drop-down" ...> object. This way the link will be active only when javascript is deactivated or not available.

Answer (score 1):

Seven years later and I still think Mathias' answer is pure genius. I recently came across the same problem under Bootstrap v4.3.1 with MS Edge and IE Explorer with scripting disabled for compatibility checks. I found the following small addition restored functionality.

```
.dropdown-toggle:focus + .dropdown-menu,
.dropdown-toggle + .dropdown-menu:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

Sorry it's so late...